# database design many to many and a owning reference

Tags: database-design

I have the following data model

```
[User] 1 - * [UserGroup] * - * [User]
```

That is, a user "owns" a UserGroup which in turn has many Users. There will always be exactly one owner to a group.
Does it make sense to have the UserGroup table reference the owner directly or should I create a "owning flag" on the many to many table instead?

Comment: Will the owning user **always** be a member of the group?

Comment: No, the owning user will **never** be a member of the group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the owner will never be a member of the group, putting them into the member-intersection sounds wrong. You would have to always exclude the owner when selecting your members.

Let your `UserGroup` reference the owner, this makes it easier to understand and allows you to enforce it using a `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: Yes, I think your initial question answered it for me, thanks :)